# How to create a dropdown menu on hover from this?

Tags: html, css

```
          <div id="navigacija">


        <nav class="clearfix">
            <ul class="clearfix">
                    <li><a href="index.html" class="on">POČETNA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="otkupplastike.html">OTKUP PLASTIKE</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">PROIZVODI</a></li>
                    <li><a href="reciklazaplastike.html">RECIKLAŽA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="oprema.html">OPREMA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="onama.html">O NAMA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactform.php">KONTAKT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" id="pull">Meni</a>
        </nav>


   </div>
```

Can someone help me to create a dopdown menu on hover of "PROIZVODI"? I need help as soon as possible, thanks.

Comment: Turn the unordered list (`<ul>`) into an option select (`<select>`). For everything else you need to know style sheets.

Comment: can you help me more? i need help asap

Comment: What do you mean by more? Could it be that you have no idea about html and css? If so, then I suggest you start reading a "getting started" guide. And one more thing: we are sorry that you apparently are under time pressure (why ever), but that is not our problem. Please stop that annoying "asap" stuff. Thanks.

Comment: I've already tried some tricks but I cant make a working dropdown menu, if you are not going to help me I'll ask you to leave this question.

Comment: If so, then _show_ some of those "tricks". You may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Do you want something like htis:-

```
.dropbtn {
    background-image:url(download.jpg);

    color: white;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 16px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:#FFF;
    min-width: 160px;
    box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

---

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">PROIZVODI</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
   <li><a href="reciklazaplastike.html">RECIKLAŽA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="oprema.html">OPREMA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="onama.html">O NAMA</a></li>
                    <li><a href="contactform.php">KONTAKT</a></li>
            </ul>
            <a href="#" id="pull">Meni</a>
        </nav>
  </div>
```

link:-https://jsfiddle.net/677p7pah/

Comment: OPREMA, O NAMA and KONTAKT are just another menu items,they shouldnt be in dropdown, I will add items to dropdown.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/dmtn2ks2/ - that's my html code for menu
I'd like to visitor get a dropdown menu (with same css if possible) when clicks on PROIZVODI.

Comment: RECIKLAZA, OPREMA and CONTACT are just another menu items, I dont want to add them to dropdown, in dropdown I'll create few thinks.

Answer (score 0):

try this asap version one:

```css
ul#drop {
  display: none;
  trasition: 3s all linear;
}

[data-toggle=drop]:hover {
 color: red;
}

[data-toggle=drop]:hover > ul#drop {
 display:block;
}
```

```html
<ul id="drop1">
<li><a href="#">menu 1</a></li>
<li data-toggle="drop"><a href="#">menu 2 (hover here)</a>
  <ul id="drop">
  <li><a href="#">sub-menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sub-menu 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: when I hover over button it just blank the menu.

Comment: sorry im not quite understand. hopefully @Razia_sultana will have solution for you

Answer (score 0):

here is the easiest way

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 20px 50px 150px;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #000000;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display: inline;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 15px 4px 17px 0;
  list-style: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

ul li {
  font: bold 12px/18px sans-serif;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-right: -4px;
  position: relative;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  background: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all 0.2s;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
  color: #fff;
}

ul li ul {
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 48px;
  left: 0;
  width: 150px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: none;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transiton: opacity 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.2s;
  -transition: opacity 0.2s;
}

ul li ul li {
  background: #555;
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #000;
}

ul li ul li:hover {
  background: #666;
}

ul li:hover ul {
  display: block;
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<ul>

  <li>Menu 01</li>
  <li>Menu 02
    <ul>
      <li>Sub Menu 01</li>
      <li>Sub Menu 02</li>
      <li>Sub Menu 03</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Menu 03</li>
</ul>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shajeeamaan/nh99nd5q/2/